# update/append Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've got a something like this data frame (simplified):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

date=dt.date(2018,1,18)
purchase_1 = pd.Series({'Store':'Store 1','Date': date,
                        'Item Purchased': 'Dog Food',
                        'Cost': 22.50,'Client':'Mark'})
purchase_2 = pd.Series({'Store':'Store 2','Date': date,
                        'Item Purchased': 'Kitty Litter',
                        'Cost': 2.50,'Client':'Den'})
purchase_3 = pd.Series({'Store':'Store 3','Date': date,
                        'Item Purchased': 'Bird Seed',
                        'Cost': 5.00,'Client':'Max'})


df = pd.DataFrame([purchase_1, purchase_2, purchase_3])
df = df.set_index(['Store', 'Date'])
df.index.names = ['Store', 'Date']


Store   Date        Client Cost   Item Purchased
Store 1 2018-01-18  Mark   22.5   Dog Food
Store 2 2018-01-18  Den    2.5    Kitty Litter
Store 3 2018-01-18  Max    5.0    Bird Seed
```

I need to update this dataframe from different reports. The first report is supposed to create a new row (store and date) and fill say Client and Item purchased data. Another report provide cost data and so on. The order in which reports come changes.
So the bottom line is: sometimes a new report is supposed to update already existing row, sometimes create a new one.
So I am looking for piece of code that can do the trick. Of course I could use a combination of **slicing, if, appending etc**, but I feel there should be a better solution.
I guess Store and Date should be used as multi-index (the combination in my case is unique), but I could not advance further .

Comment: Just a suggestion don't know if that would be useful. Looking at your needs you should go for dictionary where store and date should together should form your key and you can put rest of the data as value in a list form. Easy to update and replace. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

The magical function you want is `pd.DataFrame.combine_first`

## Reports

```
report1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Client': ['Sean'], 'Item Purchased': ['Hamster Chew']
}, pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('Store 4', date)], names=df.index.names))

report1

                   Client Item Purchased
Store   Date                            
Store 4 2018-01-18   Sean   Hamster Chew
```

---

```
report2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Cost': [3.14]
}, pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('Store 4', date)], names=df.index.names))

report2

                    Cost
Store   Date            
Store 4 2018-01-18  3.14
```

---

## Report 1 then 2

### Add row

```
df.combine_first(report1)

                   Client  Cost Item Purchased
Store   Date                                  
Store 1 2018-01-18   Mark  22.5       Dog Food
Store 2 2018-01-18    Den   2.5   Kitty Litter
Store 3 2018-01-18    Max   5.0      Bird Seed
Store 4 2018-01-18   Sean   NaN   Hamster Chew
```

### Fill in missing

```
df.combine_first(report1).combine_first(report2)

                   Client   Cost Item Purchased
Store   Date                                   
Store 1 2018-01-18   Mark  22.50       Dog Food
Store 2 2018-01-18    Den   2.50   Kitty Litter
Store 3 2018-01-18    Max   5.00      Bird Seed
Store 4 2018-01-18   Sean   3.14   Hamster Chew
```

---

## Reverse the order; Report 2 then 1

### Add row

```
df.combine_first(report2)

                   Client   Cost Item Purchased
Store   Date                                   
Store 1 2018-01-18   Mark  22.50       Dog Food
Store 2 2018-01-18    Den   2.50   Kitty Litter
Store 3 2018-01-18    Max   5.00      Bird Seed
Store 4 2018-01-18    NaN   3.14            NaN
```

### Fill in missing

```
df.combine_first(report2).combine_first(report1)

                   Client   Cost Item Purchased
Store   Date                                   
Store 1 2018-01-18   Mark  22.50       Dog Food
Store 2 2018-01-18    Den   2.50   Kitty Litter
Store 3 2018-01-18    Max   5.00      Bird Seed
Store 4 2018-01-18   Sean   3.14   Hamster Chew
```